# USB ethernet goes to sleep, has to be reconnected to restore

Tags: networking, nexus-7, usb-on-the-go

I have an old Nexus 7 tablet running LineageOS that still works but has poor battery life. I've set it up in a fixed location with AC power instead. Its location has poor wifi so I've added a [UGreen micro-USB 100Mb ethernet adapter](https://www.ugreen.com/products/micro-usb-to-rj45-lan-ethernet-adapter), which also provides power. It does work correctly when first plugged in, so the device is supported by Android - it gets an IP address and communicates without wifi.

Shortly after the screen goes to sleep, the NIC goes down. I assume this is some sort of power-saving mode. However, it doesn't come back up when the tablet is woken. It has to be unplugged and plugged back in to work. Is there a setting I can change that will leave the NIC enabled at all times? Or at least resume the ethernet connection when it wakes up.

Android version: 7.1.2
LineageOS version: 14.1

Comment: As a workaround you may want to look into how to keep the screen/display off after X minutes while preventing the phone from going into sleep mode. If phone doesn't go into sleep mode at all, your adapter should keep working.

Comment: @Firelord yes, I've considered that. It is a workaround though - the tablet only gets used for about an hour a day, so keeping the screen awake for the other 23 seems wasteful.